# How to convert a Javascript Date into sql datetime with the following format yyyy-mm-dd hh-mi-ss?

Tags: javascript, sql, datetime

i need to send a datetime from javascript to sql in this folowing format:  yyyy-mm-dd hh-mi-ss.
After creating a variable

```js
var n = new Date()
```

what should i do to fetch number in that format ?
Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with dates in more than one place, I suggest you use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). You can then do something like `moment(n).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss')` to achieve what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a slightly adapted version from MDN's [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) polyfill:

```js
if (!Date.prototype.toSQLString) {
    (function() {

        function pad(number) {
            if (number < 10) {
                return '0' + number;
            }
            return number;
        }

        Date.prototype.toSQLOString = function() {
            return this.getUTCFullYear() +
                '-' + pad(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) +
                '-' + pad(this.getUTCDate()) +
                ' ' + pad(this.getUTCHours()) +
                '-' + pad(this.getUTCMinutes()) +
                '-' + pad(this.getUTCSeconds());
        };
    }());
}

document.write((new Date()).toSQLOString());
```

Comment: Of course, this only works if you want a UTC-based result.  You would need to modify it to use different functions if you want local time.

Answer (score -2):

Steven Levithan wrote a really nice dateFormat function.

```
 var sqlDateStr = new Date().format("yyyy-mm-dd hh-MM-ss");
 console.log(sqlDateStr)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gbs93qwb/